# Adding IDs to DIV containers within an iFrame with jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, iframe

I am trying to add ID's to DIV containers in an iFrame with jQuery:

*HTML original:*

```
<iframe id="iFrame">
..
<div class="book-type">..</div>
<div class="book-type">..</div>
<div class="book-type">..</div>
..
</iframe>
```

*HTML modified:*

```
<iframe id="iFrame">
..
<div class="book-type" id="type1">..</div>
<div class="book-type" id="type2">..</div>
<div class="book-type" id="type3">..</div>
..
</iframe>
```

I tried to edit the HTML with following script but it's not working (running but no change and no error) and I'm not sure how the correct selector for the each() function works within an iframe (the DIVs to modify are wrapped in several DIVs with no IDs but classes).

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#iFrame').ready(function() {
        $('#iFrame').contents().find('div').each($('.book-type'), function(ind) {
            $(this).attr('id', 'type' + parseInt(ind + 1));
        });
    });
});
```

I would be very grateful if someone could help me!

Comment: Also, index is already an integer. No need to parse it. In fact, that may error since the `parseInt()` function [expects a string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt).

Comment: There is no change and I get no error in the JS console. I have also replaced the counter function with an alert() but it is not triggered. Therefore I suspected that something is not working with the selector for each().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be right that your selector is faulty. Simplify to just this:

```
$('#iFrame').contents().find('.book-type').each(function(ind) {
    $(this).attr('id', 'type' + (ind + 1));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved! The query whether the iFrame is loaded didn't work because an iFrame does not know **ready()** but **load()**.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#iFrame').load(function() {
        $('#iFrame').contents().find('.book-type').each(function(ind) {
            $(this).attr('id', 'type' + (ind + 1));
        });
    });
});
```